# Does anyone know what this line of Javascript code is doing in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Does anyone what the code inside the onChange is doing?
I understand that ...textData is the spread operator, but why is it spreaded inside of a { } and what is [e.target.name]: e.target.value doing, is this a new javascript syntax? Sorry for noob question!

```
setTextData({ ...textData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
```

The rest of the file looks like this, the logistic data is an Object with key value pairs.

Thank you!

```
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const logisticData = state;


  const [textData, setTextData] = useState({
    name: maybe(logisticData.logistic_name),
    location: maybe(logisticData.logistic_location),
    desc: maybe(logisticData.logistic_description),
    quantity: maybe(logisticData.logistic_quantity),
    borrowedBy: maybe(logisticData.logistic_borrowed_by),
    status: maybe(logisticData.logistic_status),
  });

  const { name, location, desc, quantity, borrowedBy, status } = textData;

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setTextData({ ...textData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }
```

Comment: `textData` represents an object in React state.  You can't simply update the existing object, because then React has no way of knowing it updated and that a render cycle must be invoked.  By setting it as `setTextData({ ...textData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })` they spread the old object into a new object and then set/override the new properties accordingly.

Comment: Ohhh thank you so much @AlexanderNied, the set/ override you mentioned helped me understand what is going on. This is a really new syntax haha ive been coding javascript for a year and have yet seen this ><, but regardless thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creates a new object with all of the properties from the `textData` object and a new property with the same value

```js
const x = 'test'

const obj = { x: 'x', y: 'y' }

const newObj = { ...obj, [x]: x }

console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this simple example. I think I understand it better now. Will accept it as an answer later because question still too fresh haha.

Sorry but if I could ask 1 more question, what is { ...obj, [x]: x } from actually as I dun think I've ever seen it before in my time coding javascript. Thank you again!

Comment: Take a look at [spread operator in object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) and [object initializer with computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names)

Comment: Thank you, will take a look at the website